# Angular 2 component used in html template chosen dynamically

Tags: angular

I am trying to render a hierarchical set of html elements, but each element will be dependent on the type of an object in an array.

I am trying to do this in Angular 2.

The idea is I have an item class

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  children: Item[];
}

class DataItem<Type> implements Item {
  public id: number;
  public children: Item[];
  public data: Type;
}
```

And I have a html template for a `hierarchical-list` like so.

```
<div class="hierarchical-list-node" *ngFor="let item of items">
  <custom-item-component [data]="item.data"></custom-item-component>
  <hierarchical-list *ngIf="item.children !== undefined"
      [items]="item.children"></hierarchical-list>
</div>
```

I want the `custom-item-component` to be specified by the item type somehow. So I can reuse the `hierarchical-list` component but render the items differently.

Potentially rendering items in the same hierarchical list differently depending on type or some other parameter.

Comment: What do you mean render them differently?  it isn't clear what "differently" means or how what you have above does not meet your criteria.

Comment: What I have above specifies a specific "custom-item-component" in the html template. I want the user to be able to specify this component. (The user of the component, not the user of the website.)

Comment: Maybe ng-content

Comment: You can create a @Input to handle the data type in your "custom-item-component". Is that what you want? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#bindings

Comment: ng-content is what I was looking for. Thanks @peeskillet